# How to initialize the session on the base of web.py in test code?

Tags: session, testing, web.py

When studying exercise 52 of LearnPythonTheHardway, I need to code for automated test for web.py server.
In app.py, I just put the function:

```
app = web.application(urls, globals())
if web.config.get('_session') is None:
    store = web.session.DiskStore('sessions')
    init = {'room': None, 'count': 100}
    session = web.session.Session(app, store,  initializer=init)
    web.config._session = session
else:
    session = web.config._session

class count:
    def GET(self):
        print 'session', session
        session.count += 1
        return session.count
```

In app_test.py, how can I initialize the session to test the status of the app?
The codes below doesn't work properly. The session.count is not 51 as I want it to be, but always 101.

```
session.count = 50
resp = app.request("/count")
assert_equal(resp.data, "51")
```

Answer (score 0):

From zhihu.com(chinese counterpart of quora) I got a resolution.

Just get value from web.input() to set the initial status in the app.py. In the  app_test.py code, use request("/count?XX=XX") to transfer the initial status to test various situations.

```
class count:
  def GET(self):
    initcount = web.input(i='')
    if init != '':
        session.count = int(initcount)

    session.count += 1
    return session.count
```

and in the test.py:

```
resp = app.request("/initcount?i=50")
assert_equal(resp.data, "51")
```